# AWS - Not receiving HTTPS requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I usually don't have this problem, but I can't receive any HTTPS request in Elastic Beanstalk environment, but HTTP requests are working.

I hope that the Load Balancer isn't redirecting requests to server, because isn't working the HTTPS with the simple application, and when I use another AWS account my server works good, with the same configurations, using HTTP and HTTPS.

I have tried:

- Open security group; (Not work)
- Change the target in the route53; (Not work)
- Kill my instances and deploy again; (Not work)
- Kill Load Balancer; (Not work)
- Deploy with Simple application; (Not work)
- Use redirect HTTP to HTTPS; (Not work)
- Use another account to deploy the same server; (Works good)

I don't receive any HTTPS request. I checked in nodeJS, and in the nginx logs.

I am using Node.js 12.16.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.14.1 with Elastic Beanstalk using nginx.

[Load Balancer config, redirecting all the requests to instance:80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0cdF.png)

Security group config:
[Security group, opened for all inbound in the port 433](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EHX5.png)

Comment: Did you try to access the LB directly and see if you get https traffic? This would rule out a route 53 issue.

Comment: Not work, error is the same,  using HTTP I get the response, and with https still loading and after some minutes, timeout error, cleaner, without errors log
Thanks for help!